# First Contact With Aliens

Tags: mathematics, cipher, pattern, number-sequence

There is a strange meteor that is caught by the Earth's gravitational pull. No one even notices it because it is so small it will simply burn up in the atmosphere -- but it doesn't. Instead, it survives it's own ball of flame and hits the ground and makes a large explosion around itself without damaging itself. The FBI is sent to investigate. When they arrive, they walk up to it (considering it didn't damage the terrain either somehow) and someone touches it. Then, it opens in two and out spills a chunk of an unknown substance. Quickly, the FBI takes this substance and analyses it. It turns out that it isn't made of atoms, but rather extremely small particles as of yet unknown to science. There is also a very specific number of them (see below). Later, 7 more meteors arrive in groups of two that don't open when touched. They determine that it was aliens who sent this as a method of first contact. You are tasked with figuring out what the aliens are trying to say.

The specific number of particles:

```
1189731495357231765085759326628007130763444687096510237472630398929628394368938606851385417791037826192671109467319770011250814712090379100731796743734310795066034135889778963516063701564426093378903676704491298015420553684572895583628349070059100700053527803417994167910380415661039371202632053679565194588000541050639089225645956273728390517346510478947339275924017657181406665107891963100562438599776573123284713703133622268903330749064267989782251376347241089399403838776802336353487386488015647307344361517009985948815714948395786204364410213510626877526354618182871370987667727947811210538166823223592542434223492304001683748879996325550122415949735113925758193735458970781929461410017390607860544944364609568177631865670612730725683560385954698661249079383939441836366429714087394460531525536916930859467078454311887230567985994343574295935555196302013099499259297751106880428744446233193167536835549133660645500354503864891378448340412153197851901926820010477766813103533626217820844099228338380596790333716786022829214360894194167507489490392484725414401283343757888271699312666737349253440203559485243867377311736041803713631286972472871869133019544599256651830979661601111810832371039900583265487623384909735259644459751120484228237800081248615389755934080311678584614166416936643066861928528904767221058640063576956410173964880899745966066690069923416746686425265109683126567307309742367633928953866464517492905936449363241983618150693448704293950524696664117345051481558188438470953270303364496925543952199054841719103820624183580129971253425153061062037317891858168288034430119953459787123793550146346318731182319574306980970497706189810797848213065902657756705967389527801683919040124228880492405718953012533494912585291118883911081680098759057149075485712493235489148233062143950433809975483000804508462748362351879948489587890412560982222938578321483532459308425213075183163083673827945015556608301783036383200862552776602948000447130469192409739540435530335024707675427645901396704264591314009718989597717204330915659948709473332432393884788055134148395951825289703677556146763005134362774185183780086557178334025688338443749586618104272550871615387251879598754033813032954034838095638412409957501796943213308907243819449196116384791585568619345494034757524022719582793541523430536899262017575104104646893689606313749194430941439322325271539214519424229356722424012569659081828052005493949830492220872040866760035036407606848533429490085631808754819521302609044193716433795258073598233482179304124368090416715111747543192683415545555859675734116278494856760442742295980633842282322629741955838720180619872258906917771879719635098385106424692589519354042368554615782981470607383473350987658856275089481797131986544408633915794210248567215702662546612191008115972997383614252881732193825536581887758942214508010700646356601725272754791967671669525480975128746772641782975235234804885096253585165945717412397625758803149241183115263936655434838499619584045056682089697720188611529896793743036605067539329483509737111270270213821217857010457410175461545729465251988316363072317655558829982390806104355281542201165913338297287318682373579544892872274950241785212844395458562930009756802165230890695593153179457146631018503317366387047047557746473286360224531878636319162210945059118535280188781890549613738638928481212114745665918149499483627456922582401052474444000020692439908945855783346014971547260729413959218454284666035149462439813617053266353262249654631879405477539305818585978217089834096474865407122613202447822846139953979134491797986540147905522829070568441421600627436677942792721603960986562174541843265405878714864134133232020967757891954111147982588992378506293628929312469064649028519619916176886911761138407397260546630460814280881125050321730616542102691192131700550534890164107365167748729437733764402334963633632107659110439158287144099747977749149266114141780378631893897650750718280697942946095780109747455765867128318270958083822661479288002186528334837087272271781814406737070874976331952626958580291554992124284553581618399286466577387837295386866090489217908149795481564641138566826051804753997085171155952405728237384843837491467670853759036877098970985981169769540689976481129113741398943481766385187492019418243074875589423040714168570927003741214626413607458895669528968690719577805417732806323480749290509707223013039802119375008230180392346558886412818619455960911929497634430343181429125867609669667669474093471234466889540388539231446663239616447605022764306207511189067268101140342023329527928979293703374757689404467669909767723384901514488727192376151979073609285083983051577273792853849704255297073008572402401350246328375514048177994439481033345888717726660761175670499461158746516847135353157759040910503140839362484606641084757765649978625516361252570319129638216744425896064595685967737564554253909504211489183404869816999548341299764689977093800959114298299069511818979311615
```

Comment: Not sure if this is significant, but this number is very close to $2^{2^{14}}$ (they are within $10^{-50}$% of each other).

Comment: @MikeEarnest: Which becomes clear once you see the picture, which starts with one complete and another half row of `1` bits.

Comment: Surely there is a more realistic way to transmit a 5000-digit number?  The premise of the problem is pretty far-fetched...

Comment: @GuntramBlohm the number isn't significant apart from its representation in binary. The 7 meteors in groups of 2 is significant though, since 2^7 is 128.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The solution is this picture:

```
11111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111
11111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111100001111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111
11111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111000000111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111
11111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111110000000011111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111
11111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111100000000001111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111
11111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111000000000000111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111
11111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111110000011100000011111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111
11111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111100000111111000001111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111
11111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111100001111111100000111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111
11111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111000011111111110000011111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111
11111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111110000011111111111000001111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111
11111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111100000111111111111000001111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111
11111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111100001111110111111100000111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111
11111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111000011111110111111110000011111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111
11111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111110000011111110011111111000001111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111
11111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111110000111111110011111111000001111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111
11111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111100001111111110011111111100000111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111
11111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111000011111111100011111111110000011111111111111111111111111111111111111111111
11111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111000011111111100011111111110000011111111111111111111111111111111111111111111
11111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111110000111111111100011111111111000001111111111111111111111111111111111111111111
11111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111100001111111111100001111111111100000111111111111111111111111111111111111111111
11111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111100001111111111100001111111111100000111111111111111111111111111111111111111111
11111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111000011111111111100001111111111110000011111111111111111111111111111111111111111
11111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111000011111111111100001111111111110000011111111111111111111111111111111111111111
11111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111110000111111111111000001111111111111000001111111111111111111111111111111111111111
11111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111100001111111111111000001111111111111100000111111111111111111111111111111111111111
11111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111100001111111111111000001111111111111100000111111111111111111111111111111111111111
11111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111000011111111111111000001111111111111110000011111111111111111111111111111111111111
11111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111000011111111111111000000111111111111110000011111111111111111111111111111111111111
11111111111111111111111111111111111111111111110000111111111111111000000111111111111111000001111111111111111111111111111111111111
11111111111111111111111111111111111111111111110000111111111111111000000111111111111111000001111111111111111111111111111111111111
11111111111111111111111111111111111111111111100001111111111111110000000111111111111111100000111111111111111111111111111111111111
11111111111111111111111111111111111111111111100001111111111111110000000111111111111111100000111111111111111111111111111111111111
11111111111111111111111111111111111111111111000011111111111111110000000111111111111111110000011111111111111111111111111111111111
11111111111111111111111111111111111111111111000011111111111111110000000011111111111111110000011111111111111111111111111111111111
11111111111111111111111111111111111111111110000011111111111111110000000011111111111111111000001111111111111111111111111111111111
11111111111111111111111111111111111111111110000111111111111111100000000011111111111111111000001111111111111111111111111111111111
11111111111111111111111111111111111111111100000111111111111111100000000011111111111111111100000111111111111111111111111111111111
11111111111111111111111111111111111111111100001111111111111111100000000001111111111111111100000111111111111111111111111111111111
11111111111111111111111111111111111111111100001111111111111111000000000001111111111111111100000111111111111111111111111111111111
11111111111111111111111111111111111111111000011111111111111111000000000000111111111111111110000011111111111111111111111111111111
11111111111111111111111111111111111111111000011111111111111100000000000000001111111111111110000011111111111111111111111111111111
11111111111111111111111111111111111111110000011111111111100000000000000000000001111111111111000001111111111111111111111111111111
11111111111111111111111111111111111111110000111111111100000000000000000000000000001111111111000001111111111111111111111111111111
11111111111111111111111111111111111111100000111111111000000000000000000000000000000111111111000001111111111111111111111111111111
11111111111111111111111111111111111111100001111111111100000000000000000000000000001111111111100000111111111111111111111111111111
11111111111111111111111111111111111111100001111111111111100000000000000000000000111111111111100000111111111111111111111111111111
11111111111111111111111111111111111111000001111111111111111000000000000000000111111111111111100000011111111111111111111111111111
11111111111111111111111111111111111111000011111111111111111100000000000000001111111111111111110000011111111111111111111111111111
11111111111111111111111111111111111111000011111111111111111110000000000000011111111111111111110000011111111111111111111111111111
11111111111111111111111111111111111110000011111111111111111110000000000000011111111111111111111000001111111111111111111111111111
11111111111111111111111111111111111110000111111111111111111110000011100000011111111111111111111000001111111111111111111111111111
11111111111111111111111111111111111110000111111111111111111110000111111000111111111111111111111000001111111111111111111111111111
11111111111111111111111111111111111100000111111111111111111110011111111110111111111111111111111000000111111111111111111111111111
11111111111111111111111111111111111100001111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111100000111111111111111111111111111
11111111111111111111111111111111111100001111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111100000111111111111111111111111111
11111111111111111111111111111111111000001111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111100000011111111111111111111111111
11111111111111111111111111111111111000011111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111110000011111111111111111111111111
11111111111111111111111111111111111000011111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111110000011111111111111111111111111
11111111111111111111111111111111110000011111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111110000001111111111111111111111111
11111111111111111111111111111111110000111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111110000001111111111111111111111111
11111111111111111111111111111111110000111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111000001111111111111111111111111
11111111111111111111111111111111100000111111111111111111111111111111111111111110011111111111111111000001111111111111111111111111
11111111111111111111111111111111100001111111111111111111111111111111111111100000000011111111111111000000111111111111111111111111
11111111111111111111111111111111100001111111111111111111111111111111111110000000000001111111111111000000111111111111111111111111
11111111111111111111111111111111100001111111111111111111111111111111111000000000000000111111111111100000111111111111111111111111
11111111111111111111111111111111000011111111111111111111111111111111100000000000000000011111111111100000111111111111111111111111
11111111111111111111111111111111000011111111111111111111111111111111000000000000000000001111111111100000011111111111111111111111
11111111111111111111111111111111000011111111111111111111111111111100000000000000000000000111111111100000011111111111111111111111
11111111111111111111111111111110000011111111111111111111111111111000000000000000000000000011111111110000011111111111111111111111
11111111111111111111111111111110000111111111111111111111111111110000000000000011111000000001111111110000011111111111111111111111
11111111111111111111111111111110000111111111111111111111111111000000000000011111111110000001111111110000001111111111111111111111
11111111111111111111111111111110000111111111111111111111111110000000000000111111111111000000111111110000001111111111111111111111
11111111111111111111111111111100000111111111111111111111111100000000000011111111111111000000011111111000001111111111111111111111
11111111111111111111111111111100001111111111111111111111111000000000000111111111111111100000011111111000001111111111111111111111
11111111111111111111111111111100001111111111111111111111110000000000011111111111111111110000001111111000000111111111111111111111
11111111111111111111111111111100001111111111111111111111000000000000111111111111111111111000000111111000000111111111111111111111
11111111111111111111111111111000001111111111111111111110000000000001111111111111111111111000000111111000000111111111111111111111
11111111111111111111111111111000011111111111111111111100000000000111111111111111111111111100000011111100000111111111111111111111
11111111111111111111111111111000011111111111111111111000000000001111111111111111111111111110000001111100000111111111111111111111
11111111111111111111111111111000011111111111111111110000000000011111111111111111111111111110000001111100000111111111111111111111
11111111111111111111111111111000011111111111111111100000000000111111111111111111111111111111000000111100000011111111111111111111
11111111111111111111111111110000011111111111111111000000000001111111111111111111111111111111000000111100000011111111111111111111
11111111111111111111111111110000111111111111111110000000000011111111111111111111111111111111100000011100000011111111111111111111
11111111111111111111111111110000111111111111111100000000000111111111111111111111111111111111110000011110000011111111111111111111
11111111111111111111111111110000111111111111111000000000001111111111111111111111111111111111110000001110000011111111111111111111
11111111111111111111111111100000111111111111110000000000011111111111111111111111111111111111111000001110000011111111111111111111
11111111111111111111111111100001111111111111100000000000111111111111111111111111111111111111111000000110000001111111111111111111
11111111111111111111111111100001111111111111000000000001111111111111111111111111111111111111111100000010000001111111111111111111
11111111111111111111111111100001111111111110000000000011111111111111111111111111111111111111111100000010000001111111111111111111
11111111111111111111111111100001111111111100000000000111111111111111111111111111111111111111111110000000000001111111111111111111
11111111111111111111111111000001111111111000000000001111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111000000000001111111111111111111
11111111111111111111111111000011111111110000000000011111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111000000000001111111111111111111
11111111111111111111111111000011111111100000000000111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111100000000001111111111111111111
11111111111111111111111111000011111111100000000001111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111100000000000111111111111111111
11111111111111111111111110000011111111000000000011111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111110000000000111111111111111111
11111111111111111111111110000111111110000000000111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111110000000000111111111111111111
11111111111111111111111110000111111100000000001111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111000000000111111111111111111
11111111111111111111111110000111111000000000011111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111000000000111111111111111111
11111111111111111111111110000111110000000000111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111100000000111111111111111111
11111111111111111111111100000111100000000001111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111100000000111111111111111111
11111111111111111111111100001111100000000011111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111110000000111111111111111111
11111111111111111111111100001111000000000011111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111110000000011111111111111111
11111111111111111111111100001110000000000111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111000000011111111111111111
11111111111111111111111100001100000000001111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111000000011111111111111111
11111111111111111111111100000000000000011111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111100000011111111111111111
11111111111111111111111000000000000000111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111100000011111111111111111
11111111111111111111111000000000000001111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111110000011111111111111111
11111111111111111111111000000000000001111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111110000011111111111111111
11111111111111111111111000000000000011111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111000011111111111111111
11111111111111111111111000000000000111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111000011111111111111111
11111111111111111111111000000000001111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111100011111111111111111
11111111111111111111110000000000011111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111100011111111111111111
11111111111111111111110000000000111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111110011111111111111111
11111111111111111111110000000000111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111
11111111111111111111110000000001111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111
11111111111111111111110000000011111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111
11111111111111111111110000000111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111
11111111111111111111110000001111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111
11111111111111111111100000001111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111
11111111111111111111100000011111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111
11111111111111111111100000111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111
11111111111111111111100001111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111
11111111111111111111100011111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111
11111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111
11111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111
11111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111
11111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111
```

Which depicts [Starfleet insignia](http://en.memory-alpha.wikia.com/wiki/Starfleet_insignia).

To get the solution, simply convert the number into binary and split it into groups of 128 with newlines in between.

Comment: You *just* beat me to it. Here's a picture that's easier to see: http://i.imgur.com/qzfHhIR.png

Comment: Wow, I thought it would take a lot longer for anyone to find this out. Apparently the people here are really good :).